# Show sublinearity of the function for a second order Cauchy problem

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, lipschitz-functions, cauchy-problem

Let us consider the following Cauchy problem:

\begin{cases}
 y''(x)=-y^3(x) \\
 y(0)=0 \\
 y'(0) = 1
 \end{cases}

I want to show that there exists a global solution for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, but I can't prove it.

---

The function $f$ is defined as $f(x,y_1,y_2)=[y_2,-y_1^3]^T$. I would like to show that **$f$ is sublinear**, i.e. $$||f(t,y)|| \leq h+k||y||$$ where $y = [y_1,y_2]^T$ but I can't show it.

I have $$||f|| = y_2^2 + y_1^6$$
but I have no clue on how to bound the last term. Any hint or answer is highly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$y''=-y^3$$
$$2y''y'=-2y^3y'$$
$$y'^2=-\frac12 y^4+c_1$$
Conditions $y(0)=0$ and $y'(0)=1$ imply $c_1=\frac12$
$$y'^2=\frac12-\frac12 y^4$$
$$y'=\sqrt{\frac12-\frac12 y^4}\qquad \text{with sign according to }y'(0)=1$$
This is a Jacobi elliptic integral.

$$y=\text{sn}\left( \frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}+c_2\:\Big|\:-1\right)$$
sn is the Jacobi sn elliptic function https://mathworld.wolfram.com/JacobiEllipticFunctions.html

The condition $y(0)=0$ implies $c_2=0$. The solution is :
$$y=\text{sn}\left( \frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\:\Big|\:-1\right)$$

[image]

Comment: I am not supposed to know elliptic functions... how can I conclude that I have global existence without using them? @JJacquelin

Comment: I was thinking about this:

$$y'(x)=\sqrt{\frac{1}{2} (1-y^4(x))}$$ then $$\int_0^{y(x)} \frac{d \phi}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}(1-\phi^4)}} = x$$ Can I use this fact in some way?

Comment: For instance: $$\int_0^{y(x)} \frac{d \phi}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}(1-\phi^4)}} =\int_0^{2^{\frac{1}{4}}}\frac{d \phi}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}(1-\phi^4)}} +\int_{2^{\frac{1}{4}}}^{y(x)} \frac{d \phi}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}(1-\phi^4)}} $$ and the first integral is convergent. Hence, for all $x$ I can compute by integration $y(x)$

Comment: thanks for your edit.Could you check please my last two comments? @JJacquelin

Comment: I cannot understand why you consider the limit $2^{1/4}$ . The limit is $y=1$. For $y>1$ the integral is not real. For $y=1$ the integral is still real $=\sqrt{2\pi}\frac{\Gamma(5/4)}{\Gamma(3/4)}\simeq 1.85407...$

Comment: You're right, I made a mistake. But my question remains: how could I show global existence using the identity $$y'^2=\frac12-\frac12 y^4$$ without computing explicitely the analytical solution? (I am not allowed to do that in this exercise)

Comment: When the integral reaches the limit at $y=1$ the derivative is $y'=0$. Then $y'$ becomes negative, thus $y'=-\sqrt{\frac12-\frac12 y^4}$ . As $x$ increases $y$ decreases up to $y=-1$ where $y'=0$  again. And so on periodically. See the graph added to my main answer.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer and patience :-) So it's periodic: is there a way to say it without computing the solution explicitely?

Comment: In integrating from $y=-1$ to $y=1$ one find the period $T=\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{d\phi}{\sqrt{\frac12(1-\phi^4)}}$. Don't look for an explicit value.  $y(x+T)=y(x)$.

Comment: How did you show that $y(x+T)=y(x)$ (which means it's periodic) (the formula for the period is clear.)